# How can I have sections and subsections aligned in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

[image: tableofcontents]

```
\documentclass[12pt,headings]{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{section A}
\subsection{subsection A}
\subsection{subsection B}
\end{document}
```

I want section A and subsection A,B to be aligned in the table of contents

Comment: I'm not sure you made it clear what you want to achieve, it would be great if you improved your question (a minimal compilable example would be great, so we can compile a document an reproduce your problem, starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`).

Comment: in content, yes.@Manuel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package you can easily achieve what you want using `\cftsetindents`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tocloft}

\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0em}{2.3em}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents 
\section{section A} 
\subsection{subsection A} 
\subsection{subsection B} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Alternativly you can use the `tocstyle` package from the KOMA-Script bundle:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents 
\section{section A} 
\subsection{subsection A} 
\subsection{subsection B} 
\end{document}

\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
```

Run twice to get

[image]

Comment: i'm sorry  but tex gave warning ; THIS IS AN ALPHA VERSION!(tocstyle) USAGE OF THIS VERSION IS ON YOUR OWN RISK!(tocstyle) EVERYTHING MAY HAPPEN!(tocstyle) EVERYTHING MAY CHANGE IN FUTURE!(tocstyle) THERE IS NO SUPPORT, IF YOU USE THIS PACKAGE!(tocstyle) Maybe it would be better, not to load this package.